# ng-repeat only works for variable {{ x }} outside of angle brackets ("<>")?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am new to angularJS.
As I was trying out the `ng-repeat`, I found a problem in my code (shown below)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-init="names=findDomains()">
<li><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="x in names" ng-click="selectDomain({{ x }})">{{ x }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

The idea is that I have a drop-down menu (e.g. with name "test") on my page. When clicked, it displays the selections, and the options are displayed as contents in `<li></li>`. All options are returned as a set by function `findDomains()` and initialized by `ng-init`.

When a particular option (content in `<li></li>`) is selected (e.g. with name "opt1"), the text of the drop-down menu is updated with the name of the option ("opt1" replaces "test"). This is implemented by function `selectDomain()`

Since it is the same content get displayed and call `selectDomain()`, I put two {{x}} calling `ng-repeat`, hoping the same option displayed calls the `selectDomain()`.

However, everything else seems working fine (`findDomains()`, `ng-repeat` and the second `{{x}}` outside `<a></a>`). But the `{{x}}` inside `<a></a>` does not work properly. When options are clicked, the dropdown menu name is not updated.

But the `selectDomain()` function is good as it works fine with plain text ( such as `ng-click="selectDomain('opt1')`).

Any guidance?

Comment: No curly braces; you're already in an AngularJS construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Per Doc**
>
> `ng-click` needs an Expression to evaluate upon click

No need of using interpolation there`ng-click` should not use `{{}}` interpolation directive, they to have direct access to scope variables inside it.

```
ng-click="selectDomain(x)"
```

Answer (score 3):

When passing variable to registered in scope function, you don't need to wrap it in `{{}}`.

Try below code, it will work:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-init="names=findDomains()">
  <li><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="x in names" ng-click="selectDomain(x)">{{ x }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Use `{{x}}` when you want to put variable value in HTML only.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this was a no brainer. I had it worked by removing the curly braces and put `ng-click="selectDomain(x)"`

Comment: why to repeat answer..with the same thing again?

Comment: @PankajParkar   I realized this answer almost a minute after I posted the question. All answers came at the same time.

Comment: Ok so you don't want to accept the answer..np..atleast do accept yours..that would help other people.. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks lad..Glad to help you.Cheers..Happy Coding :)